# PHP Assigning New Values to Array Elements

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have made the following form in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="survey.php">
   <div>
            <label class="prompt">Favorite CS courses:</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="course-web">Web Development &nbsp;
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="course-net">Networking &nbsp;
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="course-gui">GUI &nbsp;
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="course-oop">OOP
            </label>
   </div>

   <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Survey">
   </div>
</form>
```

When the user submits the form, it submits to a PHP file that I have. In the file, I have the following variable assignment to receive the `courses[]` from HTML:

```
$courses = $_POST["courses"];
```

In my PHP code, I have the following `foreach` loop so that I can print out the values from the array:

```
// output the user's favorite courses
    echo "<p>Favorite Courses:</p> <ul>";
    foreach ($courses as $course)
    {
        echo "<li><strong>$course</strong></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

The problem is that when I ouput the courses, it comes out like this:

```
Favorite Courses:

course-web
course-net
course-gui
course-oop
```

I would like to change my code so that it outputs it like this:

```
Favorite Courses:

Web Development
Networking
GUI
OOP
```

How should I go about doing this **without** changing any of the HTML code.

The best solution that I have come up with for this problem is the following code, but I feel like it could be improved a lot:

```
// output the user's favorite courses
    echo "<p>Favorite Courses:</p> <ul>";
    foreach ($courses as $course)
    {   
        if ($course == 'course-web')
        {
            echo "<li><strong>Web Development</strong></li>";
        }
        if ($course == 'course-net')
        {
            echo "<li><strong>Networking</strong></li>";
        }
        if ($course == 'course-gui')
        {
            echo "<li><strong>GUI</strong></li>";
        }
        if ($course == 'course-oop')
        {
            echo "<li><strong>OOP</strong></li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: The option texts are not transmitted to PHP, only the `value` attributes, so unless your PHP code has access to the text from another source, there's no way you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array that maps values submitted by the form to human-readable names:

```
$names = [
    'course-web' => 'Web Development',
    'course-net' => 'Networking',
    'course-gui' => 'GUI',
    'course-oop' => 'OOP',
];
```

Loop through the array of values received and look up the human-readable name in the array:

```
foreach ($courses as $course)
    if ( strlen( $name = $names[ $course ] ) ) { // Yes, assign
        echo "<li><strong>$name</strong></li>";
    }
}
```